# SharePoint Managed Metadata Crawled Property Search Scope

Tags: 2010, search, managed-metadata, search-scope, managed-property

I'm currently working on a SharePoint Search Scope that uses a property query on a managed metadata field.

Unfortunately I have had little to no luck with this so far and was looking to see if anyone had complete this before! The situation is the following:

A custom list with a managed metadata column that's based on a term set called Animals

The terms in this term set are the following:

Rhino
Elephant

I have created 4 items; 3 with Rhino and 1 with Elephant. The title of the items is Item 1, Item 2, Item 3 and Item 4.

I have run two full crawls since the creation of the column and it created the following crawled properties:

ows_taxId_Animals_x0020_Metadata**strong text**

Category: SharePoint
Property Set ID: 
Variant Type: 31
Data Type: Text
Multi-valued: No

Content using this property
This is a small sample of documents containing this property.

Sample documents:

"http://sharepoint/Lists/Search Scope Test/DispForm.aspx?ID=1"

"http://sharepoint/Lists/Search Scope Test/DispForm.aspx?ID=2"

"http://sharepoint/Lists/Search Scope Test/DispForm.aspx?ID=3"

"http://sharepoint/Lists/Search Scope Test/DispForm.aspx?ID=4"

No mappings

Include values for this property in the search index -  Enabled

**ows_Animals_x0020_Metadata**

Category: SharePoint
Property Set ID: 
Variant Type: 31
Data Type: Text
Multi-valued: No

Content using this property
This is a small sample of documents containing this property.

Sample documents:

"http://sharepoint/Lists/Search Scope Test/DispForm.aspx?ID=1"

Mapped to:

ows_taxId_Animals_x0020_Metadata

Include values for this property in the search index - Enabled

Managed Properties

**owstaxIdAnimalsx0020Metadata**

The type of information in this property: Text

as Multiple Values - Disabled

Mapped to ows_taxId_Animals_x0020_Metadata

Include values from all crawled properties mapped

Allow this property to be used in scopes - Enabled

I can successfully search for the term animal, rhino and elephant with results and refiners being built for rhino and elephant.

What I need to know do is to be able to create a search scope that allows you to search for all items containing animals but use a property query to exclude items with the Rhino value.

Unfortunately my scope never finds any items.

I have also tested using the managed property:

owstaxIdAnimalsx0020Metadata:Elephant

But again nothing is found!

Any ideas would be great appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you recreate the "Animals Metadata" column **WITHOUT** any special characters, and then **RENAME** it afterwards. This is SharePoint best practice due to how internal representations of names are stored. A space becomes *x0020* when encoded and may be further encoded to _x005F_x0020_x005F_ and so forth. You can see how this will develop into a nightmare further down the road.

Your issue is clearly an encoding problem, and not a configuration issue. Do the following:

1. Delete the field
2. Recreate the field without any special characters
3. Rename the field as you want it
4. Do a full crawl
5. Create the needed properties
6. Do another full crawl
7. Create the scopes
8. Test the scopes

Answer (score 0):

I dont know if this is any help to you but it goes through step by step, maybe you could re-go through the steps to make sure you havent missed anything out?

http://fabiangwilliams.wordpress.com/2010/05/30/understanding-managed-metadata-in-sharepoint-2010-its-impact-on-taxonomy-navigation-and-search/

and for clarity of managed meta search crawl

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff621097.aspx

hope its answers your question!